# Angular Custom focus Directive. Focus a form's first invalid input

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have created a directive to focus an input if it's invalid

```
import { Directive, Input, Renderer2, ElementRef, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[focusOnError]'
})
export class HighlightDirective implements OnChanges {
  @Input() submitted: string;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    const el = this.renderer.selectRootElement(this.el.nativeElement);
    if (this.submitted && el && el.classList.contains('ng-invalid') && el.focus) {
      setTimeout(() => el.focus());
    }
  }

}
```

I do have a reactive form with two inputs, and I've applied the directive to both inputs

```
<form>
  ...
  <input type="text" id="familyName" focusOnError />
  ...
  <input type="text" id="appointmentCode" focusOnError />
  ...
</form>
```

After submitting the form it works fine, but what I'm struggling to achieve is the following:

Expected result:
- After submitting the form if both inputs are invalid, only the first one should be focused.

Current result:
- After submitting the form if both inputs are invalid, the second one gets focused.

I don't know how to specify "only do this if it's the first child", I've tried with the directive's selector with no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This is where I think that your form should be responsible for focusing fields not fields themselves. Since it makes more sense. Only way you could cancel focus is making input fields aware of other fields, and that doesn't make much sense

Comment: @Guillermo, I improve my answer making the directive that applied to a form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To control the inputs of a Form, I think the better solution is use ViewChildren to get all elements. So, we can loop over this elements and focus the first.

So, we can has a auxiliar simple directive :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[focusOnError]'
})
export class FocusOnErrorDirective  {
  
  public get invalid()
  {
    return this.control?this.control.invalid:false;
  }
  public focus()
  {
     this.el.nativeElement.focus()
  }
  constructor(@Optional() private control: NgControl,  private el: ElementRef) {  }
}
```

And, in our component we has some like

```
@ViewChildren(FocusOnErrorDirective) fields:QueryList<FocusOnErrorDirective>
check() {
    const fields=this.fields.toArray();
    for (let field of fields)
    {
      if (field.invalid)
      {
        field.focus();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

You can see in action in the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u6q8ce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**UPDATE** always the things can improve:

Why not create a directive that applied to the form?

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[focusOnError]'
})
export class FocusOnErrorDirective {

  @ContentChildren(NgControl) fields: QueryList<NgControl>

  @HostListener('submit')
  check() {
    const fields = this.fields.toArray();
    for (let field of fields) {
      if (field.invalid) {
        (field.valueAccessor as any)._elementRef.nativeElement.focus();
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

So, our .html it's like

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" focusOnError>
  <input type="text" formControlName="familyName" />
  <input type="text" formControlName="appointmentCode" />
  <button >click</button>
</form>
```

See the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evncpz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Even more, if we use as selector form

```
@Directive({
  selector: 'form'
})
```

Even we can remove the focusOnError in the form

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="submit(myForm)">
..
</form>
```

**Update 2** Problems with formGroup with formGroup. **SOLVED**

NgControl only take account the controls that has [(ngModel)], formControlName and [formControl], so. If we can use a form like

```
myForm = new FormGroup({
    familyName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    appointmentCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    group: new FormGroup({
      subfamilyName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      subappointmentCode: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })
  })
```

We can use a form like:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm"  focusOnError (submit)="submit(myForm)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="familyName" />
  <input type="text" formControlName="appointmentCode" />
  <div >
    <input type="text" [formControl]="group.get('subfamilyName')" />
    <input type="text" [formControl]="group.get('subappointmentCode')" />
  </div>
  <button >click</button>
</form>
```

where in .ts we has

```
get group()
  {
    return this.myForm.get('group')
  }
```

**Update 3** with Angular 8 you can get the descendants of the children, so it's simply write

```
 @ContentChildren(NgControl,{descendants:true}) fields: QueryList<NgControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @eliseo!

Comment: There is an issue with this solution if you have dynamically generated forms - fields is empty even in afterViewInit

Answer (score 1):

well, **just for funny** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9n8xek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts). If we has a formControl, we can inject ngControl that it's the control itself. So we can get the formGroup. I control the "submited" making a work-around in the app.component

```
<button (click)="check()">click</button>

  check() {
    this.submited = false;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.submited = true;
    })
  }
```

The directive is like

```
export class FocusOnErrorDirective implements OnInit {
  @HostListener('input')
  onInput() {
    this._submited = false;
  }

  //I used "set" to avoid ngChanges, but then I need the "ugly" work-around in app.component
  @Input('focusOnError')
  set submited(value) {
    this._submited = value;
    if (this._submited) {  ((is submited is true
      if (this.control && this.control.invalid) { //if the control is invalid
        if (this.form) {
          for (let key of this.keys)  //I loop over all the
          {                           //controls ordered
            if (this.form.get(key).invalid) {  //If I find one invalid
              if (key == this.control.name) {  //If it's the own control
                setTimeout(() => {
                  this.el.nativeElement.focus()   //focus
                });
              }
              break;                           //end of loop
            }
          }
        }
        else
          this.el.nativeElement.focus()
      }
    }
  }
  private form: FormGroup;
  private _submited: boolean;
  private keys: string[];

  constructor(@Optional() private control: NgControl,  private el: ElementRef) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    //in this.form we has the formGroup.
    this.form = this.control?this.control.control.parent as FormGroup:null;
    //we need store the names of the control in an array "keys"
    if (this.form)
    this.keys = JSON.stringify(this.form.value)
      .replace(/[&\/\\#+()$~%.'"*?<>{}]/g, '')
      .split(',')
      .map(x => x.split(':')[0]);
  }
}
```