# How to focus first input with error dynamically in Angular

Tags: angular, forms, focus, reactive

I need to do focus on the first input with error after validation. I get the input with error like this:

```
 getFormValidationErrors(form) {
    const errors = [];
    Object.keys(form.controls).forEach((key) => {
        const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = form.get(key).errors;
        if (controlErrors != null) {
            Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach((keyError) => {
                errors.push({
                    key,
                    keyError,
                });
            });
        }
    });

    return errors;
}
```

When I call it, I need to put the focus on the first input from the `errors` array result.

Comment: Should it show on the first control in your template? Because the order you have there is probably not the order the controls actually show in your interface.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56525783/angular-custom-focus-directive-focus-a-forms-first-invalid-input/56529873#56529873

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53924414/angular-6-reactive-forms-how-to-set-focus-on-first-invalid-input maybe this helps you